Why doesn't KJFK use stop bar lights?
I was wondering why a large airport like KJFK doesn't use stop bars for their taxiways? Specifically I was looking at taxiway KD and from google maps and from videos online it looks like they only have runway guard lights and no stop bar lights? Is there a reason behind this? or is it simply because of costs? or maybe they do have them and I'm just blind (which could be the case).
What is more confusing is that an airport like CYYZ has stop bar lights for runway 06L but no bar lights for RWY 23 taxiway H yet for some reason has them on the other side of RWY 23 on taxiway J.
Thanks in advanced, any information is helpful.
EDIT: It looks like from what I can gather, that stop bar lights are really only used for low visibility. CYYZ has a low visibility procedure chart which outlines that 06L and 05 runways are to be used in these situations. When looking around I can clearly see stop bar lights on the entrances to these runways.
Runway 06R however is not on the low visibility procedure and from images i can find does not have stop bar lights.
I asked an airline pilot, and they claimed that since KJFK is a rather old airport and in an area that generally doesn't have much low vis situations that they just decided not to install them yet. They also stated that most newer airports will install these stop bar lights regardless of where they are.
Diving in deeper it seems that KJFK has tested out stop bar lights in the past but did not install them. probably for the same reason randomhead claimed about it being the costs involved in installing the system.
As for my question with CYYZ 23 taxiway H not having stop bar lights, it does, just further back at the CAT 3 hold.
Let me know if I'm still missing something or if something I said is wrong.

Knowing absolutely nothing about JFK or how their operation works, I can confidently tell you that the answer is "money." Specifically a lack thereof.
